# Order of array returned by map

Tags: swift, swift2

This just popped in my head as one of though "I know how it works but don't know what it's supposed to be moment". Let's say I have an array:

```
struct Person {
    var name : String
    var age : Int
}

var people = [Person]()
people.append(Person(name: "John", age: 24))
people.append(Person(name: "Mike", age: 21))
people.append(Person(name: "Emma", age: 23))
```

And I want to map `people` to two different arrays with names and ages:

```
let names = people.map { $0.name }
let ages  = people.map { $0.age }
```

Questions:

1. Is there a guarantee that the result will be in the order of the original array, i.e. `names = ["John", "Mike", "Emma"]` and `ages = [24, 21, 23]`?
2. If the answer to the first question is no, is there a guarantee that `names` and `ages` are in sync?

Comment: @AntonBronnikov do you have a reference for that? Anecdotal evidence is that they are in the original order, but I don't know if Apple will implement a parallel version for `map` in the future which changes the ordering.

Comment: No, I do not have a reference (could not fish it out in 5 minutes).  That's why I answer in a comment.  My thinking is, `Array` adopts `SequenceType` protocol, which has `map()` in it, which implies that mapping will be done in the sequence's order, which in case of array is the order of an array.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, and [here's your source](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html).

"After applying the provided closure to each array element, the map(_:) method returns a new array containing all of the new mapped values, in the same order as their corresponding values in the original array."

Comment: This does not seem to be the case in Swift 5.5 anymore. Running the following test data is giving me an inconsistent result `["a": "1", "b": "'2'", "c": "0.3", "d": "%"].map { }`

Comment: @mr5 you are using the dictionary, dictionary not guaranteed to provide ordered list